# Cannot click submit button if form information is inputted

Tags: css, ruby, watir

I am using Ruby and Watir, trying to automate a page to click on a submit button after filling out the form.

This is the HTML code for the button.

```
<div class="btns_wr">
<span class="small_green_btn input" title="Submit">
<span class="link_left"></span>
<span class="link_middle">
<input id="submitEnrollmentCmdButtonId" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"     name="submitEnrollmentCmdButtonId">
</span>
<span class="link_right"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

I have tried multiple variations of class, text, titles etc but it will click the button if I do not fill thr form fields out but when I do fill the form fields out it does not click the button but errors on the very next step of course because the expected result is false.

I have tried the following:

```
browser.span(:class => 'link_middle').button(:id => 'submitEnrollmentCmdButtonId').click
browser.span(:class => 'link_middle').button(:title => 'Submit').click
```

With this, at least I got an error message:

> Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"button", :id=>"submitEnrollmentCmdButtonId"}

```
browser.span(:class => 'link_middle').span(:title => 'Submit').click
```

> Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"span", :title => "Submit"}

I am using Firefox; also this form page is opened after I click a button on a page, and this new browser window opens.

Comment: "I am using Ruby and Watir" => Then why tag the question [tag:java] but not [tag:Ruby] and not [tag:Watir]

Comment: Unless Ruby allows it you can't automate a click event, for obvious reasons.

Comment: If the form is in the newly opened browser, you need to explicitly switch to it before using it. In your examples, is `browser` the main browser or the newly opened one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button(:id => 'submitEnrollmentCmdButtonId').click
```